# The name 'MessagingCenter' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

In Xamarin.Forms I used MessagingCenter but now after migrating from Xamarin.Forms to Microsoft.Maui.Essentials I get this error:

> The name 'MessagingCenter' does not exist in the current context

In MyViewController.cs:

```cs
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Game1>(this, "Hi", (sender) =>
{
    G_RemoveLogoTestMyView();
});

public void G_RemoveLogoTestMyView()
{
    //remove image
    var LogoView = View.ViewWithTag(1234);
    if (null != LogoView)
        LogoView.RemoveFromSuperview();
}
```

And in Game1.cs:

```cs
MessagingCenter.Send<Game1>(this, "Hi");
```

[image: Image dependencies]

Is it still possible to use MessagingCenter with Microsoft.Maui?

**EDIT:** It works now. I added using Microsoft.Maui.Controls; and then I don't get the error anymore.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74950544/use-net-maui-weakreferencemanager-to-send-message-from-viewmodel-to-view AFAIK, you need to use WeakReferenceManager in MAUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use TargetFramework net6.0-ios. I added the namespace **using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;** in MyViewController.cs and in Game1.cs and then I don't get the error anymore.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0)

> MessagingCenter has been deprecated in .NET 7 and replaced with
> WeakReferenceMessenger in the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm NuGet package. For
> more information, see Messenger.

Comment: I use TargetFramework net6.0-ios in my csproj file. Will WeakReferenceMessenger work with 6.0?

Comment: It works now. I added using Microsoft.Maui.Controls; and then I don't get the error anymore.