# How do I programmatically change the Text property of a label in a .NET Maui application?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I initially have a label setup in the MainPage.xaml file like this:

```xml
<Label x:Name="Ans"
       Text=""
       FontSize="18"
       FontFamily="Verdana"
       FontAttributes="Bold"
       TextColor="White"
       Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.Row="2" 
       Padding="20,20,0,0"/>
```

What I'm looking to do at runtime is to change the `Text` property to have a value.

I tried something like this in a class that I wrote:

```cs
string retVal;
retVal = "This is a test";
Ans.Text = retVal;
```

But I'm getting a message saying:

> "The name 'Ans' does not exist in the current context."

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you doing this in the code behind, or in some random unrelated class?

Comment: Why don't you use `Binding` instead?

Comment: Either use Binding, or use [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) to send the new text to the page’s code behind, where you can do what you attempted.

Comment: @BobG Use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/ You will waste 3 months to learn how to use it, and then it will save you 3 years of fixing a code where you mixed your UI and logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can only access the Label by its `x:Name` in the code-behind that belongs to the same XAML Page/View, in your case that would be *MainPage.xaml.cs*, e.g.:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public void ChangeLabel()
    {
        Ans.Text = "This is a test";
    }
}
```

You cannot access View elements from other classes by their `x:Name` attribute. XAML files are part of the same class as their code-behind, that's why the code-behind class is marked as `partial`.

A more common approach is to use the [MVVM pattern and data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm) instead of setting the `Text` property directly.

If you need to update the UI based on something that is not part of your View or ViewModel, e.g. a different, unrelated View or ViewModel, then you can also [use the WeakReferenceManager to subscribe to messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956261/4308455) and update the UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

// ...

// Inside a method or event handler
string retVal = "This is a test";
Label ansLabel = (Label)FindByName("Ans");
ansLabel.Text = retVal;
```

With the FindByName method, you can find the named control within the current XAML page.

Hope is's Help

Comment: "The name 'Ans' does not exist in the current context." No matter how hard you look for it. It wont be there.

Comment: @H.A.H. In your code-behind file (e.g., MainPage.xaml.cs), make sure you have the proper namespace references and the appropriate using statement at the top of the file. Can u Add using Microsoft.Maui.Controls; namespace at top? I change in code. please check.

Comment: If this was MainPage.xaml.cs , he would not get "The name 'Ans' does not exist in the current context". Obviously he is accessing it from non-related class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Label inside a CollectionView!.

I had the same problem before, and it was a "CollectionView" problem.
let me explane, not just a Label but whatever Element inside a CollectionView, its x:name="whatever" will not be known in code-behind. knowing that you should consider maybe other type of UI Collections also have the same effects on it's inside Elements, idk.

I've tested all that, make a new ContentPage and replace it's xaml with this down here (don't forget to edit the namespace).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="someNamespace.TestPage"
         Title="TestPage">
<VerticalStackLayout>        
    <CollectionView>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label x:Name="LabelInsideCollectionView"
                       Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    
    <Label x:Name="LabelOutsideCollectionView"
           Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    
</VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here's the code-behind.

```
namespace someNamespace;
public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // This work.
            LabelOutsideCollectionView.Text = "Test";

            // this will not work, Error CS0103  The name 
           //'LabelInsideCollectionView' does not exist in the current context
            LabelInsideCollectionView.Text = "Test"; 
        }
    }
```

you will see that your code-behind can read "LabelOutsideCollectionView" but not "LabelInsideCollectionView".

I hope it help you or others, and hope MAUI team can fix all that.

Here's a list of the installed Versions on my machine as of the time of this Answer.

```
Installed Workload Id      Manifest Version       Installation Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------
android                    33.0.68/7.0.100        VS 17.7.33906.173
maui-android               7.0.92/7.0.100         VS 17.7.33906.173
maui-windows               7.0.92/7.0.100         VS 17.7.33906.173
maui-maccatalyst           7.0.92/7.0.100         VS 17.7.33906.173
maccatalyst                16.4.7089/7.0.100      VS 17.7.33906.173
maui-ios                   7.0.92/7.0.100         VS 17.7.33906.173
ios                        16.4.7089/7.0.100      VS 17.7.33906.173
```

I've reported just now an issue to the repository of.NET MAUI on Github.
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16182