# How to pass ObservableCollection from AppShell to another page

Tags: maui

I'm building my first MAUI application, but I need little help.
I have AppShell.xaml.cs:

```cs
private readonly HubConnection _hubConnection;
private bool isDataLoaded = false;
private int _personalId;
public ObservableCollection<string> _hubNotifications;

public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

#pragma warning disable CS0169
    _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("url").Build();
#pragma warning restore CS0169
    _hubConnection.On<Notification>("NewCallNotificationReceived", (notify) =>
    {
        ShowPopup(notify.Message);
        _hubNotifications.Add(notify.Message);
    });

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
        {
            await _hubConnection.StartAsync();
        });
    });
}
```

I want to send _hubNotifications to another page - NotificationPage.xaml.cs.
Any hint on how to solve this issue?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74950544/use-net-maui-weakreferencemanager-to-send-message-from-viewmodel-to-view